# Android Bundle corrupted when passing between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList of Parcelable objects plus a string value between two activities.  This is the code to add the data to the intent and pass it through:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayLotListActivity.class);
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putParcelableArrayList(DisplayLotListActivity.EXTRA_LOT_ARRAY, lotList);
dataBundle.putString(EXTRA_LOT_NUMBER, lotNumber);
intent.putExtra(DisplayLotListActivity.EXTRA_DATA, dataBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the code that I'm using to get the data out of the intent on the target activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle dataBundle = intent.getBundleExtra(EXTRA_DATA);
lotList = dataBundle.getParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_LOT_ARRAY);
lotNumber = dataBundle.getString(LotInquiryActivity.EXTRA_LOT_NUMBER);
```

When I check the debugger the data structures look correct before the activity is called but when I get into the target activity the data structure has been corrupted.  Specifically the ArrayList as 3 elements and it is still 3 elements in size but the second element is null.  There is then an additional extra in the bundle which contains the missing element object with a null key.  I have images of the debugger before and after but can't put them in the post because of anti-spam rules.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDipq.png
After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqbF7.png

Is there something I'm missing?  This issue occurs whether I use a Bundle or add the ArrayList directly to the intent. This is being run on a Samsung Tab 2 running 4.0.3.  This also occurs with a 4.0 emulator.

**[Edit]**
This is the Parcelable object being used (I've just left the getter and setter methods off the bottom)

```
public class Lot implements Parcelable{

private String lotn;

private String dsc1;
private String dsc2;
private String litm;
private long itm;
private String locn;
private String mcu;
private String uom1;
private String uom2;
private BigDecimal pqav;
private BigDecimal pqoh;
private BigDecimal sqoh;
private long vend;
private String rlot;
private String ldsc;
private String lots;
private String lot1;
private String lot2;
private String lot3;
private String lotsdsc;
private XMLGregorianCalendar mmej;
private XMLGregorianCalendar ohdj;

public Lot(){

}

public Lot(Parcel source){
    lotn = source.readString();
    dsc1 = source.readString();
    dsc2 = source.readString();
    litm = source.readString();
    locn = source.readString();
    mcu = source.readString();
    uom1 = source.readString();
    uom2 = source.readString();
    itm = source.readLong();
    pqav = new BigDecimal(source.readString());
    pqoh = new BigDecimal(source.readString());
    sqoh = new BigDecimal(source.readString());
    vend = source.readLong();
    rlot = source.readString();
    ldsc = source.readString();
    lots = source.readString();
    lot1 = source.readString();
    lot2 = source.readString();
    lot3 = source.readString();
    lotsdsc = source.readString();
    try{
        mmej = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(source.readString());
    }catch (Exception exc){
        mmej = null;
    }
    try{
        ohdj = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(source.readString());
    }catch (Exception exc){
        ohdj = null;
    }
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(lotn);
    dest.writeString(dsc1);
    dest.writeString(dsc2);
    dest.writeString(litm);
    dest.writeString(locn);
    dest.writeString(mcu);
    dest.writeString(uom1);
    dest.writeString(uom2);
    dest.writeLong(itm);
    if(pqav != null){
        dest.writeString(pqav.toPlainString());
    } else {
        dest.writeString("0");
    }
    if(pqoh != null){
        dest.writeString(pqoh.toPlainString());
    } else {
        dest.writeString("0");
    }
    if(sqoh != null){
        dest.writeString(sqoh.toPlainString());
    } else {
        dest.writeString("0");
    }
    dest.writeLong(vend);
    dest.writeString(rlot);
    dest.writeString(ldsc);
    dest.writeString(lots);
    dest.writeString(lot1);
    dest.writeString(lot2);
    dest.writeString(lot3);
    dest.writeString(lotsdsc);
    if(mmej != null){
        dest.writeString(mmej.toXMLFormat());
    } else {
        dest.writeString("");
    }
    if(ohdj != null){
        dest.writeString(ohdj.toXMLFormat());
    } else {
        dest.writeString("");
    }
}

/**
 *
 */
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Lot> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<Lot>() {
     public Lot createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new Lot(in);
     }

     public Lot[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Lot[size];
     }
 };
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you swap out your custom Parcelable class for an Android API class, like `Rect`?

Comment: It appears not, I just tried the same code with a Rect and it worked as expected. My custom Parcelable object contains Strings, Longs, BigDecimals and XMLGregorianCalendar objects. I represent the last two types as strings in the writeToParcel code.

Comment: Your problem is probably in that code.  Could you post it?

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  The only thing I see that jumps out at me is the lack of `describeContents()`.  I'm not sure what effect, if any, that would have.  If adding that doesn't help, I think I would start commenting out some data members to see where it goes wrong.  Since you can see in your debugger that it's null inside the `Bundle`, you know the problem exists in `writeToParcel()` (which doesn't mean there can't be a problem in your constructor, too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, for anyone that comes back to this question there's two problems that I found which I assume combined to cause this behavior.  The issues all related to the Parcelable object I was using so thanks to Todd for at least pointing me in this direction.

Firstly, I had a simple error where I had missed a readString() in my constructor of the Parcelable object.  So basically I was writing out n elements and reading in n - 1 elements.  The second issue is that Android does not implement the javax.xml.datatype library which means that XMLGregorianCalendar is not available.  As I didn't need the features of this class on the client side (there's a Java Web Application that it talks to which does use it) I just converted over to a simple java.util.Date object instead.